# How do i add a webpart to my sharepoint list (CUSTOM List)

Tags: 2013, web-part, custom-form

I'm trying to add a custom form by adding a webpart. I've noticed that when I click on the list tab > "form web parts" > "default edit form", it goes straight to the edit form and not to the section where I can add a web part.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you add a form webpart. That will just redirect you to EditForm.aspx. Instead try this:

Edit the page -> Add a page viewer web part by clicking on Add a web part. Once you've added the page viewer web part, edit the web part to show this URL: `http://siteUrl/Lists/ListName/EditForm.aspx`

Comment: I click on new record, from there I choose the GEAR icon and click edit page, but nothing happens....

Comment: @Raymound you should read up more on SharePoint basics. Check this: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-add-a-web-part-to-your-sharepoint-page.html. No need to click on new record. Just edit the page and add a webpart.

Comment: @Raymound You can also try appending this to your list URL. `?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design` to force it to show edit mode.

Comment: I added that url at the end of this https://esites.vzbi.com/sites/NY_Capital_Region/Lists/Western%20Support/AllItems.aspx but it just refreshed and didn't do anything.. is something wrong with my settings?